# VSC / PHP Intelephense does not know postgres typings

Tags: php, postgresql, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am working on a PHP class that provides functions for my postgres database.
My class `Database` looks like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Services\Database;

include_once('../server/Config.php');
include_once('../server/App/Services/Database/DatabaseConfiguration.php');

use \App\Services\Database\DatabaseConfiguration;

class Database
{

    private DatabaseConfiguration $config;
    private \PgSql\Connection|false $connection;

    public function __construct(?string $host, ?int $port, ?string $dbName, ?string $user, ?string $password)
    {
        $this->config = new DatabaseConfiguration($host, $port, $dbName, $user, $password);
    }

    public function connect(): bool
    {
        $this->connection = pg_connect($this->config->connectionInfo());
        if ($this->connection) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So nothing fancy, but my IDE (Visual Studio Code & PHP Intelephense) throws an error when it comes to the connection with the database.

```
Undefined type 'PgSql\Connection'.
```

This line forces the error:

```
private \PgSql\Connection|false $connection;
```

According to the documentation ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php)), the function `pg_connect` returns the type `PgSql\Connection|false`. Because my class is wrapped in a namespace I added a `\` in front. But both notations throw the error.

Before I was using PG I used MySql and with that I had no issue when it comes to typing.

**So how can I run my IDE with PG typings?**

**Setup:** Win10, PHP 8.1.2, PHP Intelephense v1.8.2

**Edit:** In the extension settings there is this tab:

**Intelephense: Stubs**
*Configure stub files for built in symbols and common extensions. The default setting includes PHP core and all bundled extensions*.

-> **pgsql** is added there.

Comment: Intelephense uses PhpStorm stubs, which got that change [2 months ago](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/commit/b26b02c4f55b96d5f37ad0a98fe48478db05e23a#diff-82433e7f4c7aafbfcf69aaa2f0c937580a015994181ec6a3f48d4bcd344a918aR41). Perhaps the extension maintainer has not updated them yet.